# How can I create a Spring 5 component index?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Spring Framework 5 apparently contains support for a "component index" which lives in META-INF/spring.components and can be used to avoid the need for class-path scanning, and thus, I assume, improve a webapps' startup time.

See:

- [The "what's new in spring 5" mention](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#core-container)
- [The jira issue under which the support was developed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11890)
- [Some examples of what the spring.components format seems to be from the change implementing it](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-framework/commit/dc160f6fd1f3623bf14b375c14a9b5065e660377#diff-db99676db08a87a6c93199c9c597e774)

How can I create such a component index for an existing web app I plan to upgrade to Spring 5?

(Ideally it would get generated automatically at build time with Maven I imagine, but any other workable approaches would at least give me a starting point to work from)

Comment: Have you already checked out [Stephane Nicoll's repo](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-spring-components-index), which goes through some test examples? These examples appear to utilize a [dependency in the pom](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-spring-components-index/blob/master/sample-components-200/pom.xml) to build this index based on the annotated `@Components`

Comment: Ah, no, I'd not found that - Thanks, I'll have a look!

Comment: Did you have any luck with it? I tried including the spring-context-indexer in my pom, but didn't see any difference at all in loading time, and I didn't see a index file created. So far I haven't been able to get this working

Comment: Haven't gotten back to it yet sorry - I'll be sure to report back if/when I do.

Comment: @Zipper it worked great for me. It is attached to a Maven goal, specifically the package goal, so all I had to do was run mvn package and it created my index file.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe that was my problem, I'm not sure when running in dev mode if it actually runs package

Comment: Hardly any documentation exists for this. The file created is in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring.components  in the resulting war file using the maven War plugin.  If you have an incomplete index, you will get a bean not found error. I have multiple modules dependent on each other and it is not scanning/indexing the dependent modules, so I get an error at startup.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Spring 5** Has added a new feature to improve startup performance of large applications.

*it creates a list of component candidates at compilation time.*

In this mode, all modules of the application must use this mechanism as, when the ApplicationContext detects such index, it will automatically use it rather than scanning the classpath.

**To generate the index,**  we just need to add below dependency to each module

**Maven:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.0.3.RELEASE")
}
```

This process will generate a **META-INF/spring.components** file that is going to be included in the jar.

Reference : [1.10.9. Generating an index of candidate components](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index)

Comment: Yeah - Interesting - I'll give it a shot at some point. It seems super odd that the mechanism here (at least in maven) is adding a dependency to the module though - I'd have expected it to be a maven plugin or something like that. When exactly does the generation occur in the build process?

Comment: If you read the documentation it says it needs **annotation-processor** in the IDE: *When working with this mode in your IDE, the spring-context-indexer must be registered as an annotation processor to make sure the index is up to date when candidate components are updated.* ! I don't think it's integrated with maven :-(

Comment: Finally got back to give this a try (with <scope>provided</scope> rather than optional=true if it matters), and it does indeed cause a spring.compoents file to be created - I guess adding the dependency causes the annotation processor to apply (and scope=provided avoids actually packing up the jar). Unfortunately for some reason the resulting war fails to deploy with a "No qualifying bean" exception, but that's a different issue - Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my issue there seems to have been that I needed all the dependencies which also created beans to have spring.components too, so I have it working after ensuring that - Sadly though, it seems to have very little impact on the startup time overall (looks to be saving an average of about 1 second at best).

Comment: But for jar dependency, this does not work.
Can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718184/spring-context-indexer-not-working-for-dependency-jar

Comment: In Gradle 4.6+ you may add the dependency as an `annotationProcessor`. See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies

Answer (score 16):

The `META-INF/spring.components` files are generated by an annotation processor library called `spring-context-indexer`. If you add this library as "annotation processor path" to the maven-compiler-plugin, the files will be generated automatically at build time:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This setup requires maven-compiler-plugin version 3.5 or greater.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessorPaths

Comment: How to generate the Spring Component Index when building with Maven and Kotlin:

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin + Maven:

To generate the Spring Component Index when building with Maven and Kotlin:

Kotlin Maven Plugin includes Kapt - Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool. It has a goal `kapt` which needs to execute before `compile` (it uses the sources, not the bytecode.

See  also:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#using-in-maven
- https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-core/lifecycles.html

I put the execution into a profile, so that I can get rid of this if not needed.

```
mvn install -PcreateSpringComponentIndex
```

Important: You need to keep this updated for each compilation as a matter of habit, otherwise Spring won't pick the new(ly) annotated classes as components! That also means, that if skipping the generation, you need to `mvn clean`.

Important: When using "shading" (putting all classes and resources into a single flat jar), the files `META-INF/spring.components` need to be merged! Otherwise one of them will be picked randomly and Spring won't detect any other components. (It's better to avoid shading and pack the dependencies as JARs within a JAR).

Example:

```
    <!-- May speed up the app boot by a couple of seconds. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-scanning-index -->
    <profile>
        <id>createSpringComponentIndex</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId><artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    <executions><execution><id>kapt</id><goals><goal>kapt</goal></goals><phase>process-classes</phase></execution></executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs><sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir><sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir></sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorPath><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId><version>5.3.23</version></annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId><version>5.3.23</version><scope>provided</scope></dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```