# Spring context indexer not working for dependency jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some library jar **lib.jar** (made using spring boot but packaged as normal jar without spring boot plugin) which is made of spring boot and contains `spring.components` file generated by `spring-context-indexer`.

Now, I'm using this jar in my application which also has `spring-context-indexer` and its own `spring.components` file and uses some of the bean defined in **lib.jar**.

When I start my application, spring should register all beans defined in `spring.components` of **lib.jar** and `spring.components` of **application**. But spring isn't registering any of bean of **lib.jar**.

I tried using `basePackages` property of `@SpringBootApplication` but no results.

I even copied all entries of `spring.components` of **lib.jar** into `spring.components` of my application but no result.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: r u getting exception ? How you are importing configurations from dependent jars ?

Comment: I am getting an exception that required bean `(e.g XYZ)` could not be autowired.
There is `spring.components` file in META-INF in the dependent jar. I am not importing any other configuration from it.

Comment: how you are importing configurations from lib.jar ? Have u used/Imported configuration file from lib.jar?

Comment: I haven't imported any configurations from `lib.jar`. It simply contains `META-INF/spring.components` file. So, I think spring should consider this file and register beans defined in it.

Comment: give try importing @Import({ libconfigfile.class }) in configuration class

Comment: But I have not any configuration class available in `lib.jar`. It contains `Repositories` and `Services`.

Comment: It is really hard for us to get a sense of what is happening with your project without anything to start with. Would it be possible for you to create a mockup project with said structure (a lib.jar with spring components) and another one that uses it, try to reproduce the same behavior add it on github and share it here so we can try it. It will be a lot easier for us to help and find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

If you're using Spring Data, `@SpringBootApplication.scanBasePackages` is not enough, you also need `@EnableJdbcRepositories` (or `*Jpa*` or whatsoever).

```java
package application;


// without this annotation all Repository classes
// from library will be missing
@EnableJdbcRepositories({ 
        "application",
        "library"
})
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = {
                "application",
                "library"
        }
)
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

#### Some more info

Okay, maybe I'm a bit late, but I decided to investigate this case a bit.
That's what I've found as of 2 Feb 2022:

1. All `META-INF/spring.components` files are loaded in [`CandidateComponentsIndexLoader.doLoadIndex`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.15/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader.java#L93). You can use debug to check whether it sees file from **lib** or not
2. `CandidateComponentsIndexLoader` then creates [`CandidateComponentsIndex`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.15/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndex.java), which is then stored in the component scanner, for me it is `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.scanner.componentsIndex`
3. Then in `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` [`findCandidateComponents`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.15/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java#L311) is called, which, if `componentsIndex` is not null, just gets components from that index by provided `basePackage`.

That's why missing `basePackage` is crucial.

I haven't dug into the Spring Data algorithms, but in my case Spring hadn't been generating library Repositories until I added the `@EnableJdbcRepositories` with packages.

P.S. All links represent files at the 5.3.15 tag, latest atm.